# Set other property of selected objects in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

For example, i have a ListBox with my Employees, via binding.

I want to color all the Employees that earn more than 10,000$.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to implement a property in the `Employee` that returns a string value, and then test the string value in a style's data trigger.  For instance:

```
public string SalaryRange
{
   get
   {
      if (salary <= LowRange)
      {
         return "Low";
      }
      if (salary <= MiddleRange)
      {
         return "Middle";
      }
      return "High";
   }
}
```

Then, in XAML, implement a style that uses a data trigger, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType = "ListBoxItem">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{SalaryRange}" Value="Low">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{SalaryRange}" Value="Middle">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Fucschia"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{SalaryRange}" Value="Middle">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Goldenrod"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

A lot of people learn about value converters and get all enamored with the idea of using them for this kind of thing.  But if you're using MVVM (which you should be), the above is really much cleaner:  it's clear what the property does, it's clear what the style does, it's easy to test, and there's no third piece of code hiding in a separate file that's doing all of the translation.

Comment: The class Employee implement in other project.

Comment: This is why you use the MVVM pattern.  Implement an `EmployeeViewModel` in your WPF project that wraps an instance of `Employee` and you'll be able to decorate it with whatever properties your UI view needs.

Comment: but if its declare in other project?

Comment: ok, all the classes in one project, one solution, and its still not identify if